# Cannot attach role policy in AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

In order to deploy an ECS service via the AWS CLI, I have to create a role and attach policies to it. Unfortunately, AWS denies this operation with the following message:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AttachRolePolicy operation: User: arn:aws:sts::{accountId}:assumed-role/{role-name}/botocore-session-1647247414 is not authorized to perform: iam:AttachRolePolicy on resource: role ecs-task-role with an explicit deny
```

As far as I understand, *explicit* means that there's a policy that specifically defines a deny rule for this operation. However, there's only one policy to the role I am using which has an allow role for *iam:**, which should include *iam:AttachRolePolicy*. So where does that deny rule come from?

I also tested this with the [AWS Policy Simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp?#). Strangely, the result of the simulation was that the role I am using is allowed to perform *AttachRolePolicy*.

Comment: Probably due to a SCP or permission boundaries.

Comment: As you wrote in the linked answer, I need to ask someone with more rights than me to check this.